# How to fix the Duplicate Object Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 row each row has a button each index, Once i open it, it will show a textbox you can input anything once you submit it. it will pass the data to the result; and put it to the this.name so here is my problem once i saved it to my web api i got the duplicate data which i i don't know why anyone could help me.

here i input

```
Index(0)
0: {ArrayList: 0, itemName: 'TEST001A'}
1: {ArrayList: 0, itemName: 'TEST001B'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Index(1)
0: {ArrayList: 576, itemName: 'TEST002A'}
1: {ArrayList: 576, itemName: 'TEST002B'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But Once i Saved it, it gives me this result

```
TEST002A
TEST002B
TEST002A
TEST002B
```

here i retrieved my data once i close the dialog!

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
   this.names= result
    })
```

here i post all my data.

```
  onSave(){
    for(const details of this.fg.value?.displayArray){
            this.service.pD(details).subscribe((resp) =>{
              this.test001 = resp.id;
              for(let i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++){
                this.names[i].ArrayList = this.test001
              this.service.pS(this.names[i]).subscribe((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
              })
            }
        })
      }
     }
```

here is the example of the code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6nfhr-1lrbkb

Comment: Your question is not understandable. How and what do you like to dublicate? How and where do you like to save it? What dialoge do you close? And where do you post your data to? There are to many open questions to be able to help you.

Comment: @SebastianS. i just fix my question, the problem that im facing is the duplicate that i retrieve even i tried the console.log in onSave()